# Error when use splice function in ajax before send data

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, splice

I tried to use a splice function for array in context below, but page just update after send form. Is any body here how to fix it?

```js
submitHandler: function(form) {
    a = JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray()); // a = [{"name":"1","value":"1"},{"name":"2","value":"2"},{"name":"3","value":"3"},{"name":"4","value":"4"},{"name":"5","value":"5"},{"name":"6","value":"6"}];
    a.splice(1, 4);
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function() {
            console.log("beforeSend" + a);
          },
...
```

Comment: What you want as result of the splice? The second parameter is the `deleteCount` you really want to remove 4 elements from array? But anyway, `a` is a string after using `JSON.stringify()`, and not an array anymore

Comment: You are splicing a string here not an array

Comment: I want to delete elements: {"name":"2","value":"2"},{"name":"3","value":"3"},{"name":"4","value":"4"}

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string and `splice()` is a array method.

Comment: If you want to remove those, why not just take them out of the form?

Comment: Vince Lowe are you saying that var a before use splice  should be transform to the array type?

Comment: first you splice, then you stringify

Comment: "*but page just update after send form*" - how are you setting up your `submitHandler:`? Do you have a `<button type=submit` and not cancelling it?

Comment: result [object Object],[object Object] if first splice, then stringify. Necessary result: {name: "1", value: "1"}
{name: "6", value: "6"}

Comment: Code outside of ajax: a = [{"name":"1","value":"1"},{"name":"2","value":"2"},{"name":"3","value":"3"},{"name":"4","value":"4"},{"name":"5","value":"5"},{"name":"6","value":"6"}];

a. splice(1, 4);
console.log(a);
result:
{name: "1", value: "1"}
{name: "6", value: "6"}

Comment: Of course you're going to get `[object Object]` because you're string concatenating `console.log("result " + result)`, use a comma instead `console.log("result", result);` to get object in the console.

Comment: Thank you, it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
var _array= $(form).serializeArray();
_array.splice(1, 4);
submitHandler: function(form) {
    a = JSON.stringify(_array); // a = [{"name":"1","value":"1"},{"name":"2","value":"2"},{"name":"3","value":"3"},{"name":"4","value":"4"},{"name":"5","value":"5"},{"name":"6","value":"6"}];

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function() {
            console.log("beforeSend" + a);
          },
```